# Easy way to run hook in argparse when optional argument is NOT given

Tags: python, argparse

I want a file chooser dialog to appear whenever a user does not specify a filename via the command line. Normally, for optional arguments one specifies a default argument via:

```
parser.add_argument('--foo', default='some value')
```

In my case, it would be something like:

```
parser.add_argument('--file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=chooseFile())
```

But obviously this is not going to work since it will call `chooseFile` to determine the default value whether or not the user actually provides an argument, causing a pop up window to appear even when a filename is given via the command line arguments.

Of course I could always check if the argument is provided and run code manually:

```
parser.add_argument('--file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.file is None:
    file = chooseFile()
    args.file = open(file, 'r')
```

However, I have many different frontend files that use command line arguments in similar ways (~20). I would rather keep the code as succinct and elegant as possible so that I don't fill up my codebase with repeated boilerplate as above.

**Basically what I'm looking for is a way to have a code hook run when an optional argument is NOT given. i.e. is there something equivalent to an `on_default` parameter?:**

```
def onNoFileGiven():
    file = chooseFile()
    return open(file, 'r')

parser.add_argument('--file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), on_default=onNoFileGiven)
```

This way I could define that function once somewhere, saving me a few lines of code every time I want to specify a file from command line args

Some things I've tried:

- custom type functions: these are not called when the default is used
- custom `argparse.Action` classes: the `__call__` method is not invoked when the default is used

Comment: The `default` is placed in the `args` namespace at the start of parsing.  If it is still there at the end, and is a string, it is passed through the `type` function.

Comment: Look near the end of the `ArgumentParser._parse_known_args` method for details on the closing handling of the `default` value (about line 2000 of the `argparse.py` file).